# Linkify html content to load it into webview

Tags: android, linkify

I load some `html` string to a `webview` and I want to linkify phone numbers, addresses and emails. But if i use `Spannable` to pass `html` content into `Linkify.addLinks()` method all `html` layout breaks down.

```
        String htmlText = "<some_html></some_html>";
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
        Linkify.addLinks(spannableString, Linkify.ALL);
        htmlText = Html.toHtml(spannableString);
```

So, how to linkify `html` content before I load it into `webview`?

Comment: Use HTML with an `<a href` tag

Comment: `Linkify` adds not just web links. It adds links like `tel:` for phones, links to google map for addresses and `mailto:` for emails. So it's not about `<a href`

Answer (score 0):

**In your TextView's xml layout, you should add the following:**

```
android:autoLink="all"
android:linksClickable="true"

<a href="www.google.com">Google!</a>"
```

Comment: Sorry but, I know that there is a way to add auto links in `TextView`, you can also use `LinkMovementMethod`, but the question is about `webview`

Comment: Remember to escape double quotes!